# How to fix firebase deploy broken pipe err?

Tags: node.js, firebase

I typed firebase deploy in my terminal and I keep getting this epipe broken pipe err and I don't know why this is occurring.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm- 
cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'prefix',
1 verbose cli   '-g' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v10.15.3
4 verbose exit [ 0, true ]
5 verbose stack Error: EPIPE: broken pipe, write
5 verbose stack     at Socket._write (internal/net.js:58:25)
5 verbose stack     at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:410:12)
5 verbose stack     at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:394:5)
5 verbose stack     at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:294:11)
5 verbose stack     at reallyExit (C:\Program 
Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:138:20)
5 verbose stack     at exit (C:\Program 
Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:125:5)
5 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.errorHandler (C:\Program 
Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:157:19)
5 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program 
Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:150:20)
5 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback 
(internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
6 verbose cwd C:\Users\MarkPC\Desktop\react-native-places- 
project\functions
7 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
8 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program 
Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "prefix" "-g"
9 verbose node v10.15.3 
10 verbose npm  v6.4.1
11 error code EPIPE

12 error errno EPIPE

13 error syscall write

14 error EPIPE: broken pipe, write

15 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

This is what I got from the debuglog.